# Error NullPointerException en MainActivity (¿código autogenerado?)

Tags: android-studio, activity, nullpointerexception

a ver si alguien puede ayudarme a solucionar este error en mi proyecto de Android Studio. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Me encuentro con este error en mi proyecto. En la MainActivity, cuando voy a probar el proyecto me encuentro con este error, que provoca que la aplicación se pare y salga. (Con la consecuente notificación en el emulador)

Os adjunto aquí el código del ERROR:

```
2019-01-18 19:56:42.736 5351-5351/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: pmdm.team.app, PID: 5351
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pmdm.team.app/pmdm.team.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at pmdm.team.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Y por último el código en donde da el error, en el método onCreate:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio_sesion);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // ERROR AQUÍ
    //---------------------------------------
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    //-------------------------------------------
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hola, pdorias subir el layout de tu activity?

Comment: Buenas tardes @DRE , es muy probable así como mencionan en estas respuestas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35299176/void-android-support-design-widget-floatingactionbutton-setonclicklistenerandro que tu `FloatingActionButton` no se encuentre declarado con esa id en el xml, tendrías que verificar eso, aparte de eso te recomienda mirar el siguiente enlace sobre los `NullPointerException` https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-soluci%C3%B3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados/42978#42978

Comment: Buenas y gracias por las respuestas. Veo que los NPE son un problema muy común, y que ya tenéis respondido, si preferís que borre la pregunta por favor decídmelo, si solo los administradores pueden, reportadla si lo veis necesario.

Cuando pueda intento aplicar vuestras soluciones y os intentaré responder con el resultado. Un saludo.